# Codeigniter doesn't load model

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I've got a really strange problem with codeigniter! I'll try to explain...

After realizing that I get a white page when loading my homepage on my server I've started to find the problem. The first strange thing about that is that I don't get a white page on my localhost (xampp). So after deveploping a few hours, testing just on my localhost, I decided to push my edited files on the server (via github) and tried to load my homepage there --> white page appeared.

Then, after a few hours of googling and debugging this is what I know:

I put in all controller- and model-contructors following code of line:

```
log_message('info', get_class() . ' initialized');
```

Then my log output looks like this

```
...
DEBUG - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO  - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> ModelName1_model initialized
DEBUG - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO  - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> ControllerName1 initialized
DEBUG - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO  - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> ModelName2_model initialized
DEBUG - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO  - 2015-04-07 21:12:21 --> ModelName3_model initialized
```

And then it just stops. There is nothing else, no error message - nothing. But after loading this third model the following code of line, that should be run, is:

```
$this->load->model('ModelName4_model') or die('error');
```

I tried to autoload the ModelName4_model but then the same thing happens.

So it seems that the problem is my ModelName4_model, but

1. Why does it work on my localhost?
2. I checked this model twice: it is one of my cleanest files ever.
3. The construct function is identical to all other construct functions in the other models

I want to add some differences from phpinfo()

**Server (fail) vs. Localhost (works)**

- PHP Version: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.16 vs. 5.4.16
- Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler vs. Apache 2.0 Handler
- Apache Version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) vs. Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16

Any suggestions?

***edit:***

I just realized that my ModelName4_model is not the only problem! I loaded my homepage without my ModelName4_model in autoload - so this works. After submitting a form, I get the white page again - without trying to load ModelName4_model!

What happens after submitting the form?

1. form-validation with callback function
2. if(form-validation === true) redirect ...

So there is a redirect happening. The log file looks exactly the same like before. It simply stops after loading one model. (I already checked if the problem is this last loaded model and swtiched if with another - it is not the problem, same thing happens).

If the script wouldn't stop, the next thing that would happen is

```
DEBUG - 2015-04-08 00:07:49 --> Language file loaded: language/german/form_validation_lang.php
```

And the very first line of this file is

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
```

But I can't really imagine that the BASEPATH suddenly diesappears...

***SUMMARY***

White page after:

1. Loading ModelName4_model (in autoload or in any file)
2. Submitting a form and being redirected

Any suggestions now?

***edit2: after 2 comments***

Thanks for the advice to have a look on the HTTP header in my browser. Indeed it was a 500 error. Because I've already read about this issue here on stackoverflow, I searched after these topics again. There I've got the advice to search for another logfile on my server. That was perfect. I found another logfile which gave me more information about my problem(s):

1. ModelName4_model - from the new log-file: "Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected '[' in ..." and here is this line of code

   $variable = $query->result()[0];

What's wrong with it? Remember, it works on my localhost! Maybe it is cause of PHP 5.3 instead of PHP 5.4?

2. Submitting a form and being redirected: Here is the output of the new logfile: "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method ModelName1_model::methodname() in ..."

Ok, I need to fix this. Hadn't time yet but want you keep informed.

Just wondering why these two errors are going to throw an HTTP 500 error instead of just a normal error...

Comment: Show your model and how you load it?

Comment: To help diagnose the issue you should edit your php.ini to turn these directives on (in server): `display_errors = On, html_errors = On, error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`
Also, no errors in the network tab on your browser?

Comment: Go to index.php and change the environment to development. You can see the error. Hope the errors help you to debug it. Change the line define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production'); to this: define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');

Comment: rename your model file with lowercase letters . Rename ModelName4_model TO modelname4_model. This happens with linux based server.